# Jinja2 Django Python groupby('attribute') custom sort of grouper

Tags: python, django, jinja2

So I have a Jinja2 template that I am using with Django.  I have set up a for loop that does a groupby('attribute').  Is there any way that I can do a custom sort of the grouper sets. Below is the template code.

```
{% for group in data('attribute')|groupby('property') %}
    {{ group.grouper }}
        {% for item in group.list %}
            {{ item }}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to do something like:

```
for group in data('attribute')|groupby('property')|CUSTOM ORDERING SCHEME GOES HERE
```

I know that it is possible to do:

```
for group in data('attribute')|groupby('property')|reverse
```

So what I am thinking is maybe it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [groupby](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#groupby) returns a tuple, so you can sort by accessing first element of tuple:

```
for group in data('attribute')|groupby('property')|sort(attribute='0', reverse=True)
```

Which will do the same as regular `|reverse`

But if you group by some object and want to sort it by attribute of that object, for example if `property` is a data class like that:

```
@dataclass
class InventoryItem:
    name: str
    unit_price: float
```

It is possible to sort by `unit_price` for instance:

```
for group in data('attribute')|groupby('property')|sort(attribute='0.unit_price', reverse=True)
```

Keep in mind, that if logic in template gets complicated, maybe it is time to do refactoring.